# Highcharts (Highstock) how to manually set the navigator selected range

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I wanted to only change the Navigator's selected area's range (and/or start and end position of the handles), but all I've got from the official doc is to do:

```
chart.xAxis[1].setExtremes(min, max)
```

which changes the whole navigator's range.

Here is a fiddle to better explain my case:
http://jsfiddle.net/yvw8wje4/

Any ideas how to make this possible? (if possible)

Comment: Why `xAxis[1]` ? Use `xAxis[0]` to change top pane extremes: http://jsfiddle.net/yvw8wje4/1/

Comment: Except one little thing, how come the labels on the xAxis flows in a very fluid manner once I clicked the setNavRange button? is there any way to make it look normal?

Comment: Your can always disable the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/yvw8wje4/4/

Answer (score 11):

As the comment said ,you should use xAxis[0]:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max,[Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation]);
```

[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/axis-setextremes/)

Also, you can use xAxis.range when initing your chart:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
        range: 6 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // six months
    },
}
```

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/range/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the use of xAxis.range